# Why does UFT run in the background when using Jenkins batch call

Tags: jenkins, batch-processing, hp-uft, windows-server-2003-r2

I configured Jenkins to run UFT in windows server 2003, but UFT is executing in the background. I can see the UFT process in task manager, how can I run it in the foreground instead of the background?

(ps: I did the same configuration on Win7, UFT will run in the foreground properly)
[Win 7 config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDNgn.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the runner.vbs code so that we can see what you are attempting?

Answer (score 0):

On the host computer, you should right click on the Unified Functional Testing Remote Agent and click **Settings**. This will bring up a window that includes a section for Test Handling. You should choose the not run the UFT in hidden mode(uncheck the selection box)

Please refer to this article for more details. [Reference Article](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2015/04/07/how-to-keep-uftqtp-open-after-running-from-qcalm/)

[image: HP UFT Remote Agent Settings]

Comment: Thanks, dmcgill50 ; but i didn't use ALM to call UFT; just use bach in Jenkins to call vbs (vbs will launch UFT);

Comment: it also happend when use Task sheduler to call loadrunner by bach, loadrunner will run backend, not show forend.

Comment: Then in your vbs, you must make a call to display UFT using UFT application automation code